# Functional index cross reference in Oracle

Tags: oracle, indexing, functional-programming

I have two tables like this

```
   create table A_DUMMY (
        TRADE_ID     VARCHAR2(16)
        TRADE_DATA   VARCHAR2(500)
   )

   create table B_DUMMY (
        EXT_TRADE_ID VARCHAR2(16)
        EXT_DATA     VARCHAR2(250)
   )
```

And have a view that is build something like this

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DUMMY_VIEW("TRADE_DATA", "EXT_DATA")
   AS
   SELECT A.TRADE_DATA, B.EXT_DATA FROM A_DUMMY A, B_DUMMY B 
   WHERE 
          GET_TRADE_NUMBER(A.TRADE_ID,'-') = GET_TRADE_NUMBER(B.EXT_TRADE_ID,'_') 
        OR
          GET_TRADE_NUMBER(A.TRADE_ID,'-') = B.EXT_TRADE_ID
```

To optimize this I created a functional index on TRADE_ID in A_DUMMY and EXT_TRADE_ID in B_DUMMY.

The function looks like this:

```
   create or replace function 
      GET_TRADE_NUMBER(trade in varchar2, separator in varchar2) 
   return varchar2
     deterministic
   as
   begin    
        return SUBSTR(trade, 0, INSTR(trade, separator, 1, 1) - 1);
   end;
```

Functional indexes look like this

```
   create index A_DUMMY_IDX ON A_DUMMY(GET_TRADE_NUMBER(TRADE_ID,'-'));
   create index B_DUMMY_IDX ON B_DUMMY(GET_TRADE_NUMBER(EXT_TRADE_ID,'_'));
```

Data looks like this:

```
   INSERT INTO a_dummy VALUES ('7874-LND', 'item1');
   INSERT INTO a_dummy VALUES ('7845-NY', 'item2'); 
   INSERT INTO a_dummy VALUES ('7844-NY', 'item3');

   INSERT INTO b_dummy VALUES ('7844', 'item4');
   INSERT INTO b_dummy VALUES ('7845_LND', 'item5');
   INSERT INTO b_dummy VALUES ('7874_LND', 'item5');
```

How can I make Oracle use this indexes in provided query for DUMMY_VIEW?

Because, it seems, what ever I do according to explanation plan Oracle ignores them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without sample data and the details of the function it is hard to diagnose why Oracle doesn't use your function-based indexes.

I will demo a case where the index is used:

```
/* Setup */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnc (trade_id VARCHAR2) 
   RETURN VARCHAR2 
   DETERMINISTIC IS
BEGIN
   RETURN LOWER(trade_id);
END fnc;
/

INSERT INTO a_dummy VALUES ('a', 'item1');
INSERT INTO a_dummy VALUES ('A', 'item2');
INSERT INTO a_dummy VALUES ('b', 'item3');

INSERT INTO b_dummy VALUES ('a', 'item4');
INSERT INTO b_dummy VALUES ('B', 'item5');
INSERT INTO b_dummy VALUES ('C', 'item5');
```

With this setup we notice that the index is used with simple queries:

```
SQL> SELECT A.TRADE_DATA, B.EXT_DATA
  2    FROM A_DUMMY A, B_DUMMY B
  3   WHERE fnc(A.TRADE_ID) = B.EXT_TRADE_ID;    

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0      SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer=ALL_ROWS (Cost=8 Card=3 Bytes=1197)
   1    0   NESTED LOOPS (Cost=8 Card=3 Bytes=1197)
   2    1     TABLE ACCESS (FULL) OF 'B_DUMMY' (TABLE) (Cost=5 Card=3 Bytes=411)
   3    1     TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID) OF 'A_DUMMY' (TABLE) (Cost=1 [...]
   4    3       INDEX (RANGE SCAN) OF 'A_DUMMY_IDX' (INDEX) (Cost=0 Card=1)
```

.. but unfornately not with your example query. The `OR` operator may prevent the optimizer from using the indexes. I suggest you use an equivalent query:

```
SQL> SELECT A.TRADE_DATA, B.EXT_DATA
  2    FROM A_DUMMY A, B_DUMMY B
  3   WHERE fnc(A.TRADE_ID) = fnc(B.EXT_TRADE_ID)
  4  UNION ALL
  5  SELECT A.TRADE_DATA, B.EXT_DATA
  6    FROM A_DUMMY A, B_DUMMY B
  7   WHERE fnc(A.TRADE_ID) = B.EXT_TRADE_ID
  8     AND fnc(A.TRADE_ID) != fnc(B.EXT_TRADE_ID);

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0      SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer=ALL_ROWS (Cost=16 Card=5 Bytes=1995)
   1    0   UNION-ALL
   2    1     NESTED LOOPS (Cost=8 Card=3 Bytes=1197)
   3    2       TABLE ACCESS (FULL) OF 'A_DUMMY' (TABLE) (Cost=5 Card=3 Byt[...]
   4    2       TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID) OF 'B_DUMMY' (TABLE) (Cost=1 [...]
   5    4         INDEX (RANGE SCAN) OF 'B_DUMMY_IDX' (INDEX) (Cost=0 Card=1)
   6    1     NESTED LOOPS (Cost=8 Card=2 Bytes=798)
   7    6       TABLE ACCESS (FULL) OF 'B_DUMMY' (TABLE) (Cost=5 Card=3 Byt[...]
   8    6       TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID) OF 'A_DUMMY' (TABLE) (Cost=1 [...]
   9    8         INDEX (RANGE SCAN) OF 'A_DUMMY_IDX' (INDEX) (Cost=0 Card=1)
```

As a side note: you are joining the two tables **Without filter**, a HASH join without index is perhaps the fastest way to compute the join. [Full scans are not *always* evil, indexes are not *always* good](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9422487749968).

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to be more clear, about the function and the data.

Comment: @anton_oparin:  With the data you provided it would probably be slower to use an index.  Oracle always retrieves data in blocks (2KB to 32KB), and your sample data will fit in one block.  It's faster to just read one block instead of searching through a b-tree and then reading the same block.  Try inserting several thousand rows (with something like INSERT INTO a_dummy select 'a', 'item1' from dual connect by level < 100000), and then gather stats on the table and see if it uses an index.